# rails 3 test error:Mysql2::Error: Unknown column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

guys,I get an error when I test my rails app following the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html,It said :

> test_the_truth(ClassroomTypeTest):
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'type' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `classroom_types` (`type`, `memo`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`) VALUES ('MyString', 'MyString', '2011-05-31 08:40:54', '2011-05-31 08:40:54', 980190962)

I am confused, I do not have a column in my classroom_types table,why will it appear such an error? 
Can anyone help me? Many Thanks!

Here are my models and the relationship:

The ClassroomType model:

```
class ClassroomType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
end
```

The Classroom model:

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :classroom_type
   belongs_to :teaching_building
end
```

The TeachingBuilding model:

```
class TeachingBuilding < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classrooms
end
```

And here are the corresponding tables:

classrooms:

- id
- classroom_no
- classroom_name
- classroom_type_id
- teaching_building_id

classroom_types:

- id
- name
- memo

teaching_buildings:

- id
- t_no
- name

Comment: Did you run rake db:test:load so your testing db is setup the way config/schema.rb specifies?

Comment: yeah,I ran the command after I finished the code and the migration,which are exactly the steps the Guides website tell me to do

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the problem lies with your column naming. When rails does polymorphic associations, it joins the tables with an id and selects the joined table from a xxx_type column. I could imagine that your problem goes away, if you replace "type" with (for example) "kind" within your database names and column names.

Comment: I had this problem a while ago and this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Samuel

I had encountered a similar problem but solved 
here's how

1. go to mysql localserver
2. then change the mysql column name correspoding to model having belongs_to
3. Use `"ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE oldname newname VARCHAR (10) ;"`
4. This is because rails creates default as user_id

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is column naming, check your database table column name and its type and set it according to your error message said